# OneupUploaderBundle implementation in s

Tags: symfony, file-upload, silex

Good afternoon, I have a project in silex, I want to implement OneupUploaderBundle as follows

```
use OneUp \ UploaderBundle \ OneupUploaderBundle;

$ app-> register (new OneupUploaderBundle ());
```

But it gives me the following error

```
ContextErrorException in Application.php line 126:
Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Silex \ Application ::register ()
must interface in Place Pimple \ ServiceProviderInterface,
instance of OneUp \ UploaderBundle \ OneupUploaderBundle Given, called 
in /proyect/src/app.php on line 114 and defined
```

I have read the documentation and I think my error may be in these settings, I honestly do not know where are added.

```
# App / config / config.yml
oneup_uploader:
mappings:
   gallery:
     frontend: blueimp # or any uploader you use in the frontend

# App / config / routing.yml
oneup_uploader:
   resource.
   type: uploader
```

I would appreciate any comments or suggestions to achieve this implementation.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Bundles are for Symfony2 and incompatible with Silex. Silex needs service providers.

Comment: Thanks Maerlyn, Thank you very much, you have a suggestion of a serveceprovider for the ajax file upload in a silex project

Comment: Nope, never needed to do that.